# i18next don't work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, i18next

I'm trying translate the messages in jQuery with i18next but 
don't work.

```
index.js:
========
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var msg = $.t("index.info")
}

translation.json:
================
"index": {
    "info": "The Information"
}

app.js:
=======
i18n.init ({saveMissing:   true,
            debug:         true,
            sendMissingTo: 'fallback'
           }
);

i18n.registerAppHelper     (app)
     .serveClientScript    (app)
     .serveDynamicResources(app)
     .serveMissingKeyRoute (app);
```

I need use i18next in jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to invoke 't' on jquery context. but it should be invoked on i18n context.

var msg = i18n.t(key);

Comment: There is also a newer guide here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3